# How to Count Hard Links, Symbolic links, and Junctions on an Ntfs Volume

Tags: windows, ntfs, symbolic-link, hardlink, junction

I know of some programs that claim to count one or the other, but I don't know of any that can count all three.  I would like to count all three and print out a list like so:

Hard Links:  123

Symbolic Links: 456

Junctions: 789

Is there a program or Windows command that will do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

If I use Cygwin in Windows, I can run the command:

```
find $directory -type l -exec echo symlinks \; -o -type f -links +1 -exec echo hardlinks \; | sort | uniq -c
```

Which outputs like so:

Produces output like:

> 40 hardlinks
>
> 164 symlinks